# C# Web Api Async Call

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

Am struggling to write the logic of my API to handle following async action. Basically, I will trigger the task with first call and send back 201 and triggerState back as result, to confirm task is initiated.

And now after waiting period, when I make the call, how to check if task has been completed. By right the result variable should have the status. But since I'm initiating the call back, the result is always initiated as null.

```
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task resultTask;

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get(TriggerMode triggerMode)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(triggerMode.triggerState))
        {

            DTTAsync model = new DTTAsync();

           resultTask  = Task.Run(async () =>
           {
                await model.RunDTT(triggerMode.UserName, triggerMode.TenantID, triggerMode.Procedure);
           });


            triggerMode.triggerState = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString();
            return GenerateAsyncResponse(HttpStatusCode.Accepted, triggerMode.triggerState, "15");
        }

        //If there is a triggerState - meaning we have polled before and returned a location header in the if branch above.
        else
        {
            //Do some work to check if a trigger is available
            if (DateTime.Parse(triggerMode.triggerState) < DateTime.UtcNow)
            {
                //If available, check if 
//MY LOGIC COMES HERE

                return GenerateAsyncResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, triggerMode.triggerState, "15");
            }
            else
            {
                return GenerateAsyncResponse(HttpStatusCode.Accepted, triggerMode.triggerState, "15");
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Generally polling works by looking up a value based on some id. So you would have to implement something in a database or similar to store the state of the operation. Unrelated, but `Task.Run()` is an anti-pattern. I'm not sure what you think it is accomplishing, but it actually degrades performance and scalabilty. Just await the call, don't wrap it in `Task.Run()`.

Comment: Also you can use signalr to notify your client when task is done. It's much better than check periodically.

Comment: @Crowcoder - I don't like the idea of continuous polling since afraid for long term overhead.

Comment: @aminmohammadi - thanks for the suggestion. Trying that out.

Comment: I'm not advocating polling, it is just what it looks like you were trying to do already. But nothing comes for free. Websockets (SignalR) use resources too and can consume much more resources than polling, especially as the number of connected clients increase. If you do have a large number of concurrent clients consider Azure SignalR Service to carry the burden.